# DepracationWarnings: find_element_by_name and find_element_by_xpath

Tags: python, selenium

I'm new to Selenium and am trying to hack together something that opens a webpage and auto logs-in. I've tried find_element(by=By.NAME, "email").send_keys(username), but get errors around defining "By". Code are errors are below. Could someone offer some guidance on the depracationwarning syntax.

```
# Used to import the webdriver from selenium

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import os

# Get the path of chromedriver which you have install

def startBot(username, password, url):
    s = Service("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
    
    # giving the path of chromedriver to selenium webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
    
    # opening the website in chrome.
    driver.get(url)
    
    # find the id or name or class of
    # username by inspecting on username input
    driver.find_element_by_name("email").send_keys(username)
    
    # find the password by inspecting on password input
    driver.find_element_by_name("password")
    
    # click on submit
    #driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button-block").click()
    #driver.find_element("submit_btn").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block']").click()

# Driver Code
# Enter below your login credentials
username = "email" 
password = "password"

# URL of the login page of site
# which you want to automate login.
url = "https://www.hepdata.net/login/"

# Call the function
startBot(username, password, url)
```

Errors:

DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_name is deprecated. Please use find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name) instead

DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_name is deprecated. Please use find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name) instead
driver.find_element_by_name("password")

DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_xpath is deprecated. Please use find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath) instead
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block']").click()

Comment: You don't need to worry about this, since these are just warnings and not errors, so they wont be causing any problems. But if you really really want to remove all warnings, then do as suggested by @rudizabudi

Comment: i think the error message has given you all that you need to do. i will leave you an answer which i think should help you.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the import.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

And then it's just

```
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "email").send_keys(username)
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

I made some edits and managed to get the below edits working:

```
# Find the id/name/class of username by inspecting on username input
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "email").send_keys(username)
    
# find the password by inspecting on password input
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password").send_keys(password)
    
# click on submit
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block']").click()
```